# how to make a frequency function in matlab like the excel frequency function?

Tags: excel, matlab, frequency, bins

I have a list that is sorted and I want to know how many values are in each bin? I made bins using linspace(floor(fist_element_list), ceil(last_element_list), num_bins) Is there a built in function or an easy way to do this in Matlab? All I can think of is doing it manually. I would like a frequency function like the one in excel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[hist](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html) is close.  However, it's actually grouping items into bins, not counting values.  Normally it plots, but you can get the data instead:

```
[freqs, vals] = hist(list, num_bins)
```

See also [MATLAB : frequency distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597743/matlab-frequency-distribution).

Comment: Here's the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html