# frequency dist.plot for 4D data (type double) in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 4-Dimensional data (.nc file with type double). how do i get a frequency distribution plot (line plot not histogram) for data in different range?

Comment: Adding some example will be helpfull, meantime have a look at [`tabulate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html) for generating the frequency data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
A=rand(100,1);
h=histogram(A)
x=[1:h.NumBins]
plot(x,h.Values)
```

Not sure thats exactly what you are looking for.

You could also use the not recommended function `histc` as described in this post

[MATLAB : frequency distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597743/matlab-frequency-distribution)

Comment: Rather than posting an answer without understanding the question, try commenting to clarify first.